# Could not get connection while getPartitionedTopicMetadata - Connection handshake failed

Tags: java, message-queue, apache-pulsar

I have setup apache pulsar by following this tutorial: https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/3.0.x/deploy-aws/ but I use aws ansible dynamic inventory rather than terraform inventory in a tutorial. The problem is that once I run the following code

```
import org.apache.pulsar.client.api.*;


public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws PulsarClientException {
        PulsarClient client = PulsarClient.builder()
            .serviceUrl(<my pulsar web url>) 
            .build();
        
        Producer<String> producer = client.newProducer(Schema.STRING)
        .topic("my-topic")
        .create();

        producer.newMessage()
        .value("HelloWorld")
        .send();

        producer.close();
        client.close();
        
    }    
}
```

the following error pops up:

> 10:17:35.419 [pulsar-client-io-1-7] DEBUG org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.ClientCnx - [id: 0x7b3029f5, L:/192.168.1.78:52743 - R:] Connected to broker
> 10:17:35.421 [pulsar-client-io-1-7] DEBUG org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.ClientCnx - Complete: true
> 10:17:35.604 [pulsar-client-io-1-7] DEBUG org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.ConnectionPool - Removing closed connection from pool: AbstractChannel$CloseFuture@3aac5716(success)
> 10:17:35.604 [pulsar-client-io-1-7] INFO org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.ClientCnx - [id: 0x7b3029f5, L:/192.168.1.78:52743 ! R:] Disconnected
> 10:17:35.605 [pulsar-client-io-1-7] WARN org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.ConnectionPool - [[id: 0x7b3029f5, L:/192.168.1.78:52743 ! R:]] Connection handshake failed: org.apache.pulsar.client.api.PulsarClientException: Connection already closed
> 10:17:35.994 [pulsar-client-scheduled-30-1] WARN org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.PulsarClientImpl - [topic: persistent://public/default/test-topic] Could not get connection while getPartitionedTopicMetadata -- Will try again in 384 ms

and these block of message repeats forever. I intentionally remove/hide my pulsar web URL for privacy purposes. I tried to disable my firewall but it does not resolve the error. Does anyone know where the issues are and how I can fix them? I am pretty new to apache pulsar so thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

The `Connection handshake failed` message inside the stacktrace tends to indicate that there is an issue with the TLS connection.

Is your Pulsar cluster secured in any way? Are you connecting to `pulsar://<IP>:6650` or `pulsar+ssl://<IP>:6651` ?